# Azure AD Token based Authentication for WebAPI

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, token, asp.net-core-webapi

We have developed Web API in .net Core 2.1 without authentication.

But now we are trying to add the Azure AD token based authentication.

we have registered app in azure AD and we did necessary changes in startup.cs file. and added authorize tag

When we test the API in postman we generated token we are getting Microsoft login page in Html format as result.

when we crosscheck the API in browser, its asking domain user name and password by providing the user name password we are getting the result.

Its seems some configuration or setting missing in Azure AD setup or code.

Can anyone help on this. other wise anyone share the steps for token based authentication implementation for API.

Comment: Hi Karuna, have you got the token successfully in postman and set the token in the header of the request ?

Comment: Check this for reference: https://blogs.perficient.com/2019/07/11/securing-your-web-api-using-azure-active-directory/

Comment: Could you please provide some screenshots about your steps ? Such as the step you request it in postman(the endpoint you request in postman) and some more details of your steps.

Comment: @MohitVerma thanks for the link. but in the link they mentioned for newly creating application. when we create the new application we can change the authentication type in the Wizard and processed (It will do all the staffs like registering app in AD and other things in code). but in my case we already having API. we need to add authentication for existing API.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the api , you should firstly register an app in Azure Portal .

In your api application , you can follow the below steps :

1. Install the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI`
2. Register the Azure AD Bearer authentication service in `ConfigureServices` function :

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
           .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
   ```
3. In `appsettings.json` , set the correct api configuration from Azure Portal :

   ```
   "AzureAd": {
       "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
       "Domain": "YourDomain.onmicrosoft.com",
       "TenantId": "cb1c3f2e-a2dd-4fde-bf8f-f75ab18b21ac",
       "ClientId": "83bf146d-4948-4596-a4b3-b7b2e68ac3e0"
   },
   ```

   Tenant ID ,domain name and API's ClientId could be find in Azure Portal .Then you can add `Authorize` attribute on protected controllers/actions . If you have multiple authentication schema , you can [authorize with a specific scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1) .

You client app will  uses the OpenID Connect middleware and the ADAL/MSAL to obtain a JWT bearer token for the signed-in user using the OAuth 2.0 protocol. The bearer token is passed to the web API, which validates the token and authorizes the user using the JWT bearer authentication middleware.

Comment: Thank you for the input .will follow the mentioned steps and update

Comment: I have found below link and used the source code from github and found able to achieve the authentication.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2018/03/25/azure-active-directory-authentication-easy-auth-with-custom-backend-web-api/

Comment: @Karuna , that uses easy auth which is a feature of azure app service , if you host your application on azure app service , you can use it , otherwise you still need to implement authentication from your code .